# The before proper name -> scientific product

Tags: definite-articles

I have scientific document which is about the hydrogel usage. There are two proper names of these hydrogels: *5B45* and *76AB*. They are not bought on the market, they are produced from compounds in lab and given name for the recipe/product. Should I put *the* before the names as below:

- The differences for investigated hydrogels the 5B45 and the 76AB are 2.5 and 4,6 °C and shown in the table below.

or should I omit it everywhere it the text?

Comment: This is effectively a matter of Off Topic "domain-specific usage" / jargon, but extrapolating from [*The exoproducts of the strain CHA0, **the two proteins MVaT and MvaV** were characterized...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+two+proteins+MVaT+and+MvaV%22) I'd advise you ***not*** to use the article.

Comment: This is no different than the use of articles in any other situations. It depends on context and general meaning. In the *specific* sentence in the question, it wouldn't be appropriate. (Although in other constructions, it would be fine.)